# How to customize the sorting of items on a page with jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase my request, but, basically, I have a single collection with multiple categories, all the articles of this collection are shown on a single page. It's already sorted by category, however, I'm trying to find a way to sort these categories in a specific fashion. I've tried assigning the categories weight and using that to sort, but it did not work. I'm not sure what else to try?

You can find the code for all that I've done on GitHub...https://github.com/yndrelbosch/yndrelbosch.github.io

I'm trying to make this page: https://yndrelbosch.github.io/tutorials/ use a custom sorting for the categories on the page...

The code for that page is here: /pages/tutorials.html

the articles in the collection are here: /_tutorials/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Always, ALWAYS post code directly, not links to external sites with code. If those links go down, this question is useless for people searching for solutions to similar problems. Post code, preferably a complete, minimal example of what you are trying to do/can't get to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***pages/tutorials.html***, your `{% assign categories = site.tutorials | group_by:"category" | sort: "category-weight" %}` will definitely not work.

As `category-weight` is not a key in `site.tutorials` documents, the sort filter will fail silently.

#### Saving some typing

We can avoid setting category in tutorials front matter by defining defaults variable depending on document path.

Let's change _tutorials organization :

```
_tutorials
├── advanced
│   ├── adding-next-previous-to-blog.md
│   └── ...
├── getting-started
│   ├── getting-started-with-jekyll.md
│   └── ...
└── setup
    ├── jekyll-on-windows-2.md
    └── ...
```

Add some defaults in `_config.yml` :

```
defaults:
  - ...
  - { scope: { path: "_tutorials/advanced" }, values:  { category: "Advanced" } }
  - { scope: { path: "_tutorials/getting-started" }, values:  { category: "Getting started" } }
  - { scope: { path: "_tutorials/setup" }, values:  { category: "Setup" } }
```

#### Create a reference for tutorials categories order

In `_config.yml`, add

```
# this is used to display tutorials in the right categories order
# be sure to match default category names defined in site.defaults
tutorials-categories:
  - "Setup"
  - "Getting started"
  - "Advanced"
```

Note that moving categories order from `pages/tutorials.html` to `_config.yml` is made to centralize configuration. It helps to stay in synch between defaults settings and categories order.

#### Let's display our tutos in the right categories order

In `pages/tutorials`, we can do something like :

```
{% assign categories = site.tutorials | group_by:"category" %}

{% comment %} ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
We loop site.tutorials-categories to sort categories in a defined order
++++++++++++++++++++++++++ {% endcomment %}
{% for category in site.tutorials-categories %}

  {% assign current-category = categories | where:"name", category | first %}
  {% assign category-tutorials = current-category.items %}

  <h2>{{ category }}</h2>
  <ul>
  {% for item in category-tutorials %}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```